# Filtering a subset of a nested dataset

Tags: dataset, associations, filtering

I have a nested dataset (a result of a JSON import done by Mathematica, curated for this example):

```
dataset=Dataset[
<|"sports" -> {
<|"id" -> 3, "name" -> "Baseball", "hasOfferings" -> True|>, 
<|"id" -> 4, "name" -> "Basketball", "hasOfferings" -> True|>, 
<|"id" -> 5, "name" -> "Beach Volleyball", "hasOfferings" -> False|>}|>
]
```

How do I extract a subset of the above, containing only the rows matching `"hasOfferings" -> True` ? I.e. the desired result would be:

```
Dataset[
<|"sports" -> {
<|"id" -> 3, "name" -> "Baseball", "hasOfferings" -> True|>, 
<|"id" -> 4, "name" -> "Basketball", "hasOfferings" -> True|>}|>
]
```

Based on the fact that

```
dataset[All, {1,2}]
```

works as desired, I would have guessed that something like the following

```
dataset[All, "hasOfferings" == True]
```

would yield the desired filtering of the rows matching the condition, but it does not. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost there:

```
 dataset[All, Select[#hasOfferings &]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work: `Query[Select[#hasOfferings == True &]]@dataset[#sports &]`